# Uploadcare widget shows "Incorrect value" string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, uploadcare

I'm integrating UploadCare into my Rails app. I have a field in my `Book` model called `image_url`, a plain string.

Uploading images works fine, but the problem is when the widget is initialized in a form for a model that already has an existing value of `image_url` that **is not an UploadCare url.**

As long as the `image_url` field has an UploadCare image url, the widget works fine. But if it has something like: `http://i.imgur.com/foobar.jpg` it says "Incorrect value". It just seems that the widget knows the image isn't on UploadCare so it says Incorrect value for some reason.

I'm using the `uploadcare-rails` gem.

Is there some way to tweak this behavior?

Comment: How exactly do you want to tweak this behavior? Widget can't show the arbitrary link as it's value: it don't know the real file name, size and can't show preview. Maybe the better solution will be to not use the widget with such links.

Comment: @homm: Just an empty value would be good enough for our use case.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit tricky, but still possible. This is the code, which should work for your case:

```
function patchWidget(widget) {
  function onChange(file) {
    // Fire only once
    widget.onChange.remove(onChange);
    if (file.state() == 'rejected') {
      file.fail(function(reason) {
        if (reason == 'baddata') {
          var value = $(widget.inputElement).val();
          widget.value(null);
          $(widget.inputElement).val(value);
        }
      });
    }
  }
  widget.onChange.add(onChange);
}
```

It will reset the value of the widget if it is not the Uploadcare URL (URL with the path, which starts with UUID), but will preserve the value of the hidden input. So if the user submits the form, a not an UploadCare URL will be saved.

Full example: http://jsbin.com/gucuqoc/watch?html,js,output